# SSL Socket OutputStream Write Slow only on Windows

Tags: java, windows, ssl

**Server:** Linux

**Tested Clients:** OS X, CentOS, Windows

**Server/Client Programming Language:** Java

```
Server-side

SSLServerSocketFactory sslserversocketfactory =
                (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
SSLServerSocket sslserversocket =
                (SSLServerSocket) sslserversocketfactory.createServerSocket(9999);
SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) sslserversocket.accept();

InputStream inputstream = sslsocket.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader inputstreamreader = new InputStreamReader(inputstream);
BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(inputstreamreader);

String string = null;
while ((string = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(string);
    System.out.flush();
}
```

Server Program executed with this option

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=mySrvKeystore -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=123456
```

**Certificate:** Created with keytool on Linux

```
keytool -genkey -keystore mySrvKeystore -keyalg RSA
```

**Client Side**

```
....
    SocketAddress sa = new InetSocketAddress(ip, port);
....
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
....
      sslContext.init(.........., new SecureRandom());

      SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
      this.clientSock = socketFactory.createSocket();
      this.clientSock.connect(sa, this.ConnectTimeout);       
      this.clientSock.setSoTimeout(this.RecvTimeout);
      this.clientSock.setReuseAddress(true);
....

public boolean writeTo(String procname, BufferedOutputStream out, byte[] data)
{....
    out.write(data, 0, data.length);
    out.flush();
....}
```

**Results:** Everything works great but only client program from windows, it gets delayed when write to outputstream.

1. SSL Socket connection made
2. Set Output/Input stream
3. Write data into output stream
4. flush

... for 4-5 secs, it got stuck here with no reason at this point ...

1. close

The delay happens on the same java client simple program executing from Windows 7, Windows XP.
Tested from 3 different windows machine.
Everywhere else works great.

So I tried to build SSL simple clients with C and PHP, works great from Windows.
That means only Java clients method is not working.

Does anyone have any idea or similar experience before?
I'v seen some posts suspecting on WINS/DNS, but it seems like it's not the case here.
Also the funny thing is, it's always about 4-5 seconds of delay from every windows machine.

Thanks a lot for your comments in advance.

Comment: Maybe it's just the way windows API work. Maybe your question should be "Since socket write is slow on windows.. what can I do in the meantime?"

Comment: Why are you waiting 4-5 seconds between the last write and the flush()?

Comment: No, I am just saying it gets stuck there for 4-5 secs. I should comment that out or explain better.

Comment: @handicop You certainly should. At the moment it reads like your program gets stuck for 4-5 seconds before it flushes and you are complaining about the 4-5 seconds it gets stuck before it flushes as though it was somebody else's fault.

Comment: ****Correction****
It gets delayed when flush is called.
As expected, if I don't call flush, the data never gets across the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've experienced a similar issue. Using tcpdump, I found that the TCP connection from client to server (SYN, SYN-ACK, ACK) happens almost instantaneously, then a mysterious pause, then the client actually sends the data.

The tcpdump output indicates that, immediately after connecting, the client (running on Windows) sends a NetBIOS name request (presumably to find out the name of the server, perhaps so it can choose an appropriate certificate or something) and the server immediately replies with an ICMP response saying the NetBIOS UDP (137) port is unreachable. It looks like the windows client ignores that response. After 1.5 seconds the windows client sends another NetBIOS name request, and the server sends the same ICMP response. After another 1.5 seconds the windows client sends a third and final NetBIOS name request, and the server sends back the same ICMP response. The socket data is finally transmitted 1.5 seconds after that.

So it looks like windows tries three times to determine the NetBIOS name of the server, and waits 1.5 seconds each time. Eventually (after 4.5 seconds) it gives up and sends the data. I think this explains the 4-5 second pause you reported.

One workaround to eliminate the pause is to add a 'hosts' file entry for the server. (It doesn't really matter what hostname you use within that file. The mere presence of an ip address avoids the need for the NetBIOS name resolution.) There are probably other alternatives too (e.g. add the server name to WINS or DNS or something, depending on what your windows machine is using for name resolution).

Comment: Thank you @Mr Weasel, it's been a while, I will try your research in depth and get back here soon.

Answer (score 0):

You're complaining about writing and you're only showing the reading code. What does the writing code look like? If you're not using a buffered stream or writer in the stack to the `SSLSocket` you can get data size explosions of up to 44 times, which would affect performance severely. I did some extensive testing over the Internet a few years ago and the conclusion was that with properly written code, SSL isn't any worse than 3 times as slow as plaintext.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to add client side.

Comment: Get rid of the flush inside the write method. Only flush before you read the response. At present you are getting zero benefit from the BufferedOutputStream, so you're getting exactly the problem I described above. Also get rid of that insecure TrustManager, which doesn't look as though it would even compile.

Comment: Thanks @EJP. But I thought that if it doesn't get flushed, whatever I wrote on the output stream would not be actually transferred over the network. Also  the question is why this is happening only on windows os. I will try to remove TrustManager and test again.

Comment: @handicop That's correct. That's what you want. You want to push as much data as possible at a time at the SSLSocket, so you don't get the overhead I described above. You only need to flush once, at the end of the request. That's why I said to flush before you read the response. What happened when you tried it?

Comment: The client should connect to server and send predefined size of data and close the connection. So the write method will have write and flush calls. The same issue remains on windows machine. After flush call, it hangs for about 5 seconds. I was looking at the client and server side and left log message to check the time elapsed. On the same network, every other os does not act this way, only windows os does that.